# passing object between forms and views

Tags: django-views, django-forms

I have a problem with passing object between views and forms and back.

On first form i check token (GET) with email - if it's ok - you can go further. If not - go away :D

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    try:
        token = request.GET['token']
    except:
        return render(request,'error.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/vote/')
    else:
       form = LoginForm(initial={'token': request.GET['token']})

    return render(request,'login.html', context = {'form':form})
```

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=254,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'required'}))
    token = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        try:
            voter = Person.objects.get(email__iexact=cleaned_data['email'],token__exact=cleaned_data['token'])
            
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid email')
```

It works.

But now i try to go to voting form.
And I want to use voter object (which is set in LoginForm). Of course this is different form, so I have to pass it. I thought about session, but there's no request.session in form. This is in view, but there's no voter...  or is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always when I'm stuck for many minutes, I wrote the question and after few minutes I got excellent solution, so I want to share it with you:

I moved checking into view and use form.add_error. And I don't need token hidden field anymore:

forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', max_length=254,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'required'}))
```

views.py:

```
def login(request):
    try:
      token = request.GET['token']
    except:
        return render(request,'error.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                voter = Person.objects.get(email__iexact=form.cleaned_data['email'],token__exact=token)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/vote/')
            except Person.DoesNotExist:
                form.add_error('email','Invalid email')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render(request,'login.html', context = {'form':form})
```

And now I can pass voter into next form using request, session, whatever :D